# Issue with layout when adding an AD banner in an Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, banner

I'm trying to add an AdMob banner to the bottom of my android app, and I recently started learning XML, and I'm having issues.

My main.xml is all within a FrameLayout.
So my menu is displayed with content behind it, and I want the ads to begin displaying when the button is pushed, when the menu disappears.

Right now, when the button is pushed, the ads appear where I want them, but the content behind it disappears, and basically the app becomes dead.
If I hit anywhere outside the menu (where a game should be going on), the app will crash: with a null pointer exception on where fieldview should be.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/admob">

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.dozingcatsoftware.dodge.FieldView   <------- (Where the content is)
android:id="@+id/fieldView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"/>      
....  <-------- The menu, the menu view and buttons
```

Comment: Post your entire layout xml as well as the relevant code. You might need to post FieldView as well.

Comment: Hi William, thank you for replying. 

Here's the entire full xml: http://shrib.com/SINDeWsb
and here's FieldView: http://shrib.com/a1jFBFw0

Comment: OK, I can't work out what you are attempting to do. I recommend cutting it down to a trivial example that still fails. Either you will see what you are doing wrong or you can post that and we might be able to help you.